# No me funciona onmousedown ni onmouseup desde el movil

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una función pero el problema es que **onmousedown** ni **onmouseup** me funciona desde el celular, cuáles funciones debería usar para reemplazar estas y que funcione? ya que básicamente es necesario porque va a ser una app no una página web.

```js
var record = document.getElementById("record");

record.onmousedown = function() {
record.innerHTML = "Grabando...";
record.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

record.onmouseup = function() {
record.innerHTML = "Grabado";
record.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
#record{
color: #fff;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
border-radius: 50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<span id="record">Grabar</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las funciones para celular análogas a `onmouseup` y `onmousedown` son `ontouchstart` y `ontouchend`

```
record.ontouchstart = function() {
record.innerHTML = "Grabando...";
record.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

record.ontouchend = function() {
record.innerHTML = "Grabado";
record.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```